# How do I tell Ruby's OpenSSL library to ignore a self-signed certificate error?

Tags: ruby, soap, wsdl, openssl, certificate

I'm trying to use Ruby's SOAP support as follows:

```
SERVICE_URL = 'https://...'
...
def create_driver
  ::SOAP::WSDLDriverFactory.new(SERVICE_URL).create_rpc_driver
  driver.options['protocol.http.ssl_config.verify_mode']  = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
  driver.options['protocol.http.ssl_config.client_cert']  = @certificate_path
  driver
end
```

but the call to `new(SERVICE_URL)` blows up with "`OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError: certificate verify failed`."  How do I do the equivalent of `driver.options['protocol.http.ssl_config.verify_mode']  = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE` for the first call to retrieve the WSDL itself?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I put a file called "`soap/property`" on my load path, e.g.:

```
- lib/
    - foo.rb
    - foo/
        - bar.rb
    - soap/
        - property
```

And put this in the file:

```
client.protocol.http.ssl_config.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
```

Alternatively, if you have multiple settings with the same prefix, you can use the group syntax:

```
[client.protocol.http]
ssl_config.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
...
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
...
  OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
  ::SOAP::WSDLDriverFactory.new(SERVICE_URL).create_rpc_driver
...
```

Comment: You're saying I redefine `VERIFY_PEER` to be the value of `VERIFY_NONE`? That's risky since I can't be certain whether the code for checking the verification method checks for the value of VERIFY_NONE or VERIFY_PEER. Redefining constants is an absolute last resort.

Comment: I should say, though, that it *will* work. It may be a last resort because it's sneaky, but if all else fails...

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled across this url : https://gist.github.com/fnichol/867550  .This might be useful for anyone who is having similar problems.