# ignoring SSL error with Ruby SOAP

Tags: ruby, wsdl

I'm trying to use wsdl on an https url. with reference to [How do I tell Ruby's OpenSSL library to ignore a self-signed certificate error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1555006/how-do-i-tell-rubys-openssl-library-to-ignore-a-self-signed-certificate-error/5471896#5471896)

when i try this:

... OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE ::SOAP::WSDLDriverFactory.new(SERVICE_URL).create_rpc_driver ...

I'm getting this error:

SyntaxError in ReportsController#wsdlCaller

/rails-root/app/controllers/reports_controller.rb:220: dynamic constant assignment ... = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE::SO...

How do i resolve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

ok so i changed the syntax to

const_set(OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER, OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE)

and i resolved the dynamic constant assignment error. that was probably because i was trying to assign a value to a constant in a method.

i'm now stuck at a new error: uninitialized constant OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER. does anyone know why this is happening?

help! thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try below to disable the certificate verification:

```
require 'httpclient'
client = HTTPClient.new
client.ssl_config.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
```

Otherwise you can try to update your certificates instead (example for macos below):
$   brew upgrade ruby
$   brew update --system
$   gem update httpclient
$   brew install openssl
$   brew link openssl --force